# OpenLayers Google Satellite error

Tags: openlayers, javascript, google-maps

When I try to insert in QGIS the Google Satellite OpenLayers Plugin it gives me an error ("Printing and rotating of JavaScript API based layers is currently not supported" and the image appears overwritten with "for development purposes only".

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the whole thing but nothing changed...

Any suggestions?

[image: When I try to insert the Google Satellite OpenLayers Plugin it gives me an error ("Printing and rotating of JavaScript API based layers is currently not supported" and the image appears overwritten with "for development purposes only"]

Comment: If you want the "for development purposes only" message to disappear you will need to click on the link provided in the message and follow the instructions see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977913/google-maps-shows-for-development-purposes-only

Comment: thank you for the answer. I still do not understand what i am sopoused to do. The link you gave me directs to a plugin for google chrome, while my problem is in QGis and i do not even have chrome on my pc (sorry if i did not make that clear!)

Comment: The link I gave goes to stack overflow question, that asks about the `For development purposes only` message from Google Maps, and the answer is `Google Maps is no longer free. You have to associate a credit card so that you can get billed if your site has requests that exceed the $200 credit they give you monthly for free. `      You can use the service without associating a credit card, but if you do you get the message.  It doesn't matter that you are trying to use the service in QGIS through a plugin